# Generate sequential invoice numbers with tenant prefix under concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Invoice` model which has a `before_create :generate_invoice_number` callback.
I also have two tenants for EU (prefix 11) and US (prefix 12). The generated format should be tenant-00000001. For regular invoices it seems to be no problem but i run a subscription service and when renewal interval starts (first of month) a lot of invoices (~1000) get generated at the same time via a background job.

```
def generate_invoice_number
  retries = 0

  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      Invoice.where(tenant_identifier: tenant.name).lock(true)

      latest_invoice = Invoice.where(tenant_identifier: tenant.name).order(invoice_number: :desc).first
      next_sequence_number = latest_invoice ? latest_invoice.invoice_number.split('-').last.to_i + 1 : 1
      padded_sequence = next_sequence_number.to_s.rjust(8, '0')

      self.invoice_number = "#{tenant.invoice_number_prefix}-#{padded_sequence}"
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, ActiveRecord::Deadlocked => e
    raise e if retries >= 10
  
    puts "RESCUED #{retries}"
    retries += 1
    sleep(0.2 * (2 ** retries))
  
    retry
  end
end
```

This is my test setup for it:

```
it "generates unique invoice numbers under concurrency" do
  threads = []

  generated_invoice_numbers = Concurrent::Array.new

  50.times do
    threads << Thread.new do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        invoice = create(:invoice)
        generated_invoice_numbers << invoice.invoice_number
      end
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
    end
  end

  threads.each(&:join)

  expect(generated_invoice_numbers.uniq.length).to eq(generated_invoice_numbers.length)
end
```

I'm using mysql as db server and the `invoice_number` has a unique index on it.

**Problem:** I'm still getting duplicate errors even when rescuing and timeout errors. `before_create` is probably not the best place to do that? or how could i optimize that?

**EDIT variant with mysql trigger (using hairtrigger)**

```
trigger.before(:insert) do
  <<-SQL
    DECLARE seq_number INT;

    SELECT next_sequence_number INTO seq_number
    FROM tenant_invoice_sequence_numbers
    WHERE tenant_identifier = NEW.tenant_identifier
    FOR UPDATE;

    IF seq_number IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET NEW.invoice_number = CONCAT(NEW.tenant_identifier, '-', LPAD(seq_number, 8, '0'));

      UPDATE tenant_invoice_sequence_numbers
      SET next_sequence_number = seq_number + 1, updated_at = NOW()
      WHERE tenant_identifier = NEW.tenant_identifier;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO tenant_invoice_sequence_numbers(tenant_identifier, next_sequence_number, created_at, updated_at)
      VALUES (NEW.tenant_identifier, 2, NOW(), NOW());

      SET NEW.invoice_number = CONCAT(NEW.tenant_identifier, '-', LPAD(1, 8, '0'));
    END IF;
  SQL
end
```

**Problem** with this is i get deadlocks as i lock the table. And i have to reload the object because rails does not know anything about the trigger (i wonder how rails knows about the id after creation).

Comment: I suggest generating invoice numbers upfront end just picking an unused one when needed.

Comment: What's about moving to the database layer for consistency? If this list of tenants is stable enough, you can create two sequences for that numbers and trigger function that choose needed sequence, invoke next value and finally build string in needed format. It seems to me that it will be more reliable than callbacks, threads and other application-level solutions

Comment: Alternatively: move all of your invoice creation (or just the invoice number assignment) to a separate background queue that is processed strictly sequentially. If you don't have any concurrency in the first place, there's no need for transactions / rollbacks etc. when determining the next invoice number.

Comment: @mechnicov sounded like a great idea - i edited my initial question with the trigger. i get deadlocks now.

Comment: @spickermann how would that prevent race conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using redlock for distributed locking and rescue of not unique numbers with retry. Looks like it fixes the problem for now.

```
def generate_invoice_number
  retries = 0

  begin
    $redlock_client.lock("invoice_number_lock_#{tenant.name}", 2000, retries: 10) do |locked|
      if locked
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          tenant_sequence = TenantInvoiceSequenceNumber.find_or_create_by!(tenant_identifier: tenant_identifier)
          padded_sequence = tenant_sequence.next_sequence_number.to_s.rjust(8, '0')
          self.invoice_number = "#{tenant.invoice_number_prefix}-#{padded_sequence}"

          tenant_sequence.increment!(:next_sequence_number)
        end
      else
        raise "Unable to acquire lock to generate invoice number"
      end
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
    raise e if retries >= 10

    retries += 1
    sleep(0.2 * (2 ** retries))
  end
end
```

Also added an extra model to keep track of the next number.

```
create_table "tenant_invoice_sequence_numbers", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "tenant_identifier", null: false
  t.integer "next_sequence_number", default: 1, null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["tenant_identifier"], name: "index_tenant_invoice_sequence_numbers_on_tenant_identifier", unique: true
end
```